# Why is my notification bar duplicated and offset on home screen?

Tags: screen, 5.1-lollipop, home-screen

The defect can be seen at the top right corner of the home screen. There is also a black bar running down the right side of the home screen. When compared with the second picture from Google Chrome, the notification bar appears normal and there is no black bar.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

What exactly has gone wrong and how can it be fixed? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but is your wallpaper a screen capture? If so, is the right-side of the notification bar in the image?

Comment: The black bar on the left is part of the problem. The icons top left are duplicated and merged. But in Chrome, it's fine. Yes the image was PrtSc. Got a new case with built in keyboard. So much easier to take screenshots now! ^_^ YAY!

Comment: I hope that answers it. I wasn't entirely sure what you meant :-/ :-)

Comment: Hahahahaaa, I just checked and that was the problem. I know what you mean now. The reason I dismissed it because I could have sworn that I cropped it before setting it, but it obviously didn't work...  lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two notification bars- the real one and a second one that is part of the wallpaper. Check the wallpaper image and adjust as necessary.